# get first element from relationship eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a question about queries, how can i get the first element from a relationship hasMany in Laravel, i have a chats table with a relationship hasMany messages, i try with this, and take() and limit(), but without success

```php
$chats = Chat::with(['messages' => function ($query) {
    $query->first();
}])->get();
```

Comment: Can't you just do it the other way around, Message::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->chat?

Comment: no, i need to get all the chats with their first message, with that query i get only the first message from db and his relationship chat

Comment: I see. You could make a new relation like 'firstMessage', and have a ->first() inside the relation itself

Answer (score 3):

I think, it can be exists another good solution, but with this i can make what i want

Chat model class:

```php
public function firstMessage()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Message::class);
}
```

the query from controller:

```php
Chat::with('firstMessage')->get();
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, it worked! one for each element. For some reason using the limit(1) suggested in the other answers only returned one relationship element for all the queried elements instead of one for each one.

Comment: too elegant. thanks  

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making a separate property for this and having the logic inside it. So this is inside Chat class:

```
public function getFirstMessageAttribute() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
}
```

And then you can call it like:

```
$chats = Chat::with('messages')->get();
$chats[0]->firstMessage; //
```

Comment: Chat::with('firstMessage')->get()

Comment: but if i want to make a big query, something like this
```php
     Chat::with('firstMessage')->get();
```

it make this error

Call to undefined method App\Message::addEagerConstraints()

Comment: are you sure you added the relation code to the Chat class?

Comment: yes, i have another 6 relations with another models but, nothing wrong

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: You're mistaking a mutator for a relationship. `public function getFirstMessageAttribute()` will make the attribute `$chat->firstMessage` available, but this does not work as a relationship via  `with('firstMessage')`. This doesn't need to be a mutator; `public function firstMessage()`, then `$chat->firstMessage`, and `with('firstMessage')` will all work.

Comment: yes, that is a solution, but it's an api, so, i can't access to the properties getters from the client(im using vue), but you give me an idea

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$chats = Chat::with(['messages' => function ($query) {
    $query->limit(1)->latest();
}])->get();
```